# Win32 Batch Script, Search a String Data and Determine the Group Name

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a data text file in which data is divided into groups as follow:

```
[Group 1]

string-1

string-2

string-3


[Group 2]

string-4

string-5

string-6

string-7

string-8

[Group 3]

string-9

string-10
```

When the batch script runs, it will ask for an input which will be one of the strings; it then will search for the input string in the file and report the group the string is found.  (The strings have no spaces.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
@echo off

set /p "$UserInput=Enter the string : "

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a $c=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in (data.txt) do (
 set $line=%%a
 if "!$line:~0,1!"=="[" set /a $c+=1
 if /i !$line!==%$UserInput% goto:next
)
exit /b

:next
echo User is group is : [Group!$c!]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "user="
    set /p "user=user name ? "

    if defined user (
        for /f "delims=" %%a in (
            'findstr /r /i /x /c:"\[.*\]" /c:"%user%" "users.txt"'
        ) do if not "%%a"=="%user%" ( set "group=%%a" ) else (
            echo Member of :!group!
        )
    )
```

This code will search the input file for the lines containing groups or the user name, iterating over this generated list. For each line, if it does not match the user name it is a group and the name is stored in a variable. If the line contains the user name, it is member of the last seen group. As the group name is stored in a variable, it is echoed to console.

So, if a user is member of more than one group, all the groups where the user is found are echoed to console.

Comment: Thank you for your help! What does 'findstr /r /i /x /c:"\[.*\]" /c:"%user%" "users.txt"' do?

Comment: @user3754282, read the file `users.txt` and return lines that ignoring case (`/i`) exactly (`/x`) contains some of the regular expressions (`/r`) indicated as: the name of the user (`/c:"%user%"`) or a group name that consist of a opening square bracket (`\[`, it needs to be escaped) followed by any character (`.*`) and a closing bracket (`\]`, also escaped). So, only the list of groups and the user name is returned. Whenever the user appears in the list, it belongs to the group in the previous line.

Comment: @user3754282, The code is asking the user to enter an user name. Will you do a search when you don't have a username?